# How to Display Correct Times for Users Regardless of Their Time Zones

Tags: date-time, timezone, multiple-lines-of-text

I have an InfoPath form on my List. One of the controls on this form is called LoggingTest of type "Multiple lines of text". Below are the settings for this column on my control:

[image]

The purpose of the above is to log the user's comments and when they did it. Below is how the control works on my form. It displays the username "PC" and the date and time of when the comments were entered.

[image]

The only issue I have is that the time displaying on the screenshot above is **2 hours behind my local time**.

I had another user from another time zone test and their time is displaying **3 hours behind their local time**.

I know there's a setting in **Site Settings>Regional Settings** to change this but I believe this will still display time incorrectly for users in different time zones.

I also tried **click my user name>My Settings>My Language And Region>Always user my personal settings**. However, I get an error that says "*Sorry, something went wrong*". I talked to our Admin and he said it's because we don't have MySites where this information is stored, so this won't work.

Is there a way to get the time to display correctly for users regardless of the time zone they are located?

Comment: Are you willing to add JavaScript to the `DispForm.aspx`?

Comment: I'm willing to try anything. Could you please direct me on how to accomplish? Also, will there be negative effects of doing so?

Comment: You could add a CEWP to the page that would use JavaScript to get the date/time fields, convert them to Date objects, convert to local time, then change the text. You'll need to read up on using HTML/JavaScript in a CEWP in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Form Load Rule that populates the datetime fields with "Now()"?

You can also try adding code-behind to the InfoPath form to build a Time Zone conversion function. http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/25611/88903.aspx

Comment: Yes I have tried the form load rule Now(). The same issue persists where it displays 2 hours behind for me and 3 hours behind for the user I tested with from the East Coast. Are there any other alternatives?